# wifi button, settings and hence networks are not showing

Tags: wireless, gnome

I accidentally killed something gnome process of wifi during top command execution. Now wifi buttton from desktop top bar and wifi settings in settings menu are not showing.

```
command ---> nmcli d
o/p--->

DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
usb0     ethernet  connected    Wired connection 1 
docker0  bridge    connected    docker0            
wlo1     wifi      unavailable  --                 
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; but it's likely by just logging off & logging in again all will be returned (*release details may allow different responses*)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have added the details now. Sorry New to this world :P

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Are you using the desktop, the server, or the "core" version of Ubuntu? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1385553/edit) and add these information.

Comment: Hello friend, I am using core version of ubuntu on my laptop

Comment: Please provide your release, eg. is it Ubuntu Core 16, Ubuntu Core 18, Ubuntu Core 20. You've also used a GNOME tag, but GNOME doesn't run on Ubuntu Core systems as they are server intended for *headless* operation on devices, appliances or in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This restores several control center missing features (wifi is one of them)

update libraries first

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install or reinstall gnome control center

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```